# Getting "505 Version Not Supported" error in Chrome. How to access the page?

Tags: http, telnet

I have tried to access a web page via the URL and I see a blank white page.

So, in chrome, I hit F12 and bring up the console which says this:

```
GET ****** 505 (HTTP Version Not Supported)
```

I check the Network tab to see the request and response headers.

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 505 HTTP Version Not Supported
Date: Wed, 07 Jun 2017 09:59:17 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.17 (Debian)
Content-Length: 0
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=98
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Request:

```
GET /step-1 HTTP/1.1
Host: *****
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/58.0.3029.110 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6
```

Ok, so I open up a linux terminal and type:

```
telnet *hostname* 80
```

Connects fine, so

```
GET /step-1
```

Then, I immediately get `connection closed by foreign host`

So, even with HTTP/0.9, it doesn't seem to be able to retrieve the web page.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your Chrome browser up to date? I just updated to 59.0.3071.86

Comment: That is not the issue. The same error occurs in IE and FF and when using telnet: GET /step-1 HTTP/1.1

Comment: Could the website simply be down or having issues?

Comment: Nope, the website is fine. it is only that page. In reality this is a challenge that I have been set. I am meant to figure out how to access this page, but I am completely stumped.